# Android : java.lang.NoSuchField Exception for mSurface while trying use surface from native

Tags: android, android-ndk, stagefright

I want to feed buffer of the surface from Native code. So I get the surface from SurfaceView's SurfaceHolder's getSurface method. Now all I want is to use it from the native to feed buffer to render image. I have included SurfaceClinger/Surface.h. But when I try to get mSurface property, it throws error saying java.lang.NoSuchFieldException for mSurface.
Any suggestion in this regard will be helpful.

code snippet:

```
Surface       mSurface;
SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

mSurface = mSurfaceHolder.getSurface();

try{
    class myClass = mSurface.getClass();
    String fieldName = "mSurface";
    Field field = myClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccesssible(true);
    int surfacePtr = field.getInt(mSurface);
    nativeInterface.DrawOnSurface(surfacePtr);
}
catch(Exception ex){}
```

Thanks.

Comment: post the error code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From gingerbread onwards, the field name is different. By replacing fieldname from 'mSurface' to 'mNativeSurface' the problem is solved. for froyo and below 'mSurface' will work.